# How can I build just the core libraries (libstd, libcore, ...) from source, without building the whole compiler toolchain?

Tags: build, rust

My current work flow requires me to rebuild the Rust compiler nearly every day to get the "standard crates" like `libstd` for another target platform (`arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`).

This is not ideal. I already use the nightly compiler, which is able to target the ARM platform, but it does not include the standard libraries for ARM, but only for my host machines platform.

How can I build just the libraries from source, without building the whole compiler toolchain with 3 compiler stages, llvm, jemalloc, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I'm 100% sure, but something like this might work.

Run:

```
rustc -v --version
```

Make a note of the commit-hash, then navigate to your rust src folder and run:

```
git checkout *your commit-hash*
```

Finally compile with:

```
rustc -O --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf rust/src/libstd/lib.rs
```

This should compile the library to your current working directory.

See http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/20/rust-language-c-embedded/ for the original, and a more detailed explanation.

Comment: That is aborting due to missing dependencies. I tried to build the libraries in the right order, but no success so far.

Comment: When building in the correct order (libcore first), it fails because of general compiler errors? Maybe a ton of missing compiler and linker flags...

Comment: Are you making sure the compiler and the source you are compiling from are from the same commit? I tried compiling libcore, but got errors, after some searching I found [this](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/20/rust-language-c-embedded/). After I checked out the commit that matched my compilers commit-hash, it compiled just fine.

Comment: Yes my compiler source tree was matching the version of my installed binary. Maybe I should just wait for the beta release today, and give that a go.